# Delegates and Function pointers

Tags: c#, delegates, function-pointers

Delegates in .Net and function pointers in C are they similar or Conceptually same? Pls help me understand; pls excuse me if this is a basic or trivial question. Any responses greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

They are virtually the same thing.  However, they are also type-safe, unlike function pointers.  You can find an overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

Comment: Like other .NET types, there is run-time enforcement of type-safety. C++ function pointers _are_ typed, and so offer plenty of type-safety as long as you don't go casting the type-safety away. Other important features in .NET delegates not present in C++ function pointers include the ability of a delegate to include the invocation target object (i.e. the instance used to call an instance method), and to include multiple invocations in a single delegate instance (i.e. "multicast").